# How do I find what Java version Tomcat6 is using?

Tags: java, tomcat, find, version

Is there a OS command to find what Java version Tomcat6 is using?
I need to use a Perl (including system()) command.

I using Linux.  Ubuntu and CentOS

Is there something like?

```
     tomcat6 version
```

Comment: Do you want to find that from inside Tomcat (i.e. a servlet or JSP or utility class), or from the outside?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann see my new edits.

Comment: I'd like to know in WINDOWS how to do that

Comment: **Windows**: `catalina -version` (if you have the bin folder in your `Path`) or edit %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\version.bat by adding `pause` at the end, then run this file (**version.bat**). You'll see a line containing **JRE_HOME**.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

At first you need to understand first, that Tomcat is a Java application.
So, to see which java version Tomcat is using, you can just simply find the script file from which Tomcat is started, usually catalina.sh.

Inside this file, you will get something like below:

```
catalina.sh:#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
catalina.sh:#                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty.
catalina.sh:  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
catalina.sh:  JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
catalina.sh:    echo "Using JAVA_HOME:       $JAVA_HOME"
```

By default, JAVA_HOME should be empty, which mean it will use the default version of java, or you can test with: echo $JAVA_HOME

And then use "java -version" to see which version you default java is.

And vice versa by setting this property: JAVA_HOME, you can configure which Java version to use when starting Tomcat.

Answer (score 99):

> /usr/local/tomcat6/bin/catalina.sh version

Comment: This prints JRE_HOME. But if I do `echo $JRE_HOME` it prints nothing. Then where is tomcat getting JRE_HOME from?

Comment: When I run this command it states "JVM version: 1.8.0" whereas running "ps -ef | grep tomcat" -version from the answer below shows java version "1.7.0". Which of you is right?

Comment: `/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh version` for tomcat 8

Comment: Great answer, gave me an error and within it i saw the version directory name location

Answer (score 25):

Once you have started tomcat simply run the following command at a terminal prompt:

*`ps -ef | grep tomcat`*

This will show the process details and indicate which JVM (by folder location) is running tomcat.

Comment: k how to find the tomcat version from this ?

Comment: Very useful and accurate way to find it. Thank you

Comment: this is accurate, ps -ef | grep tomcat, shows the path of runtime java in the output. Use that java path, call /xx/yy/java -version. catalina.sh version can show a different jre_version compared to the tomcat launch version.

Answer (score 6):

If tomcat did not start up yet , you can use the command `\bin\cataline version`  to check which JVM will the tomcat use when you start tomcat using   `bin\startup`

In fact ,`\bin\cataline version` just call the main class of [`org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat60/blob/b3a72da34ff12f939534afa1c7deeff19df66248/java/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.java) , which is located inside the `\lib\catalina.jar` .  The `org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo`  gets the JVM Version and JVM Vendor by the following commands:

```
System.out.println("JVM Version: " +System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
System.out.println("JVM Vendor: " +System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor"));
```

So , if the tomcat is running , you can create a JSP page that call `org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo` or just simply call the above `System.getProperty()` to get the JVM Version and Vendor . Deploy this JSP to the running tomcat instance and browse to it to see the result.

Alternatively, you should know which port is the running tomcat instance using . So , you can use the OS command to find which process is listening to this port.  For example in the window , you can use  the command `netstat -aon` to find out  the process ID of a process that is listening to a particular port  . Then go to the window task manager to [check the full file path of this process ID belongs to.](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/configure-task-manager-to-display-full-path-of-running-processes/) .The java version can then be determined from that file path.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use the [Probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) application and just look at its System Info page.  Much easier than writing code, and once you start using it you'll never go back to Tomcat Manager.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Tomcat manager app to find out which JRE and OS versions Tomcat is using.  Given a user `tomcat` with password `password` with a role of `manager`:

Tomcat 6:

```
curl http://tomcat:password@localhost:8080/manager/serverinfo
```

Tomcat 7/8:

```
curl http://tomcat:password@localhost:8080/manager/text/serverinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, launch cmd prompt and route to the path(usually bin) where you have your tomcat startup script.

```
C:\opt\isv\tomcat-7.0\grid\bin>version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\opt\isv\tomcat-7.0\grid"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\opt\isv\tomcat-7.0\grid"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\opt\isv\tomcat-7.0\grid\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\opt\isv\devtools\jdk1.8.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\opt\isv\tomcat-7.0\grid\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\opt\isv\tomcat-7.0\grid\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Server built:   Jul 18 2014 05:34:04
Server number:  7.0.55.0
OS Name:        Windows 7
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   x86
JVM Version:    1.8.0_45-b15
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
C:\opt\isv\tomcat-7.0\grid\bin>
```

Comment: He clearly stated that the OS he is using are: Linux. Ubuntu and CentOS. your answer related to none of them.

Answer (score 0):

After installing tomcat, you can choose "configure tomcat" by search in "search programs and files". After clicking on "configure Tomcat", you should give admin permissions and the window opens. Then click on "java" tab. There you can see the JVM and JAVA classpath.

Comment: this doesn't address the users question and it seems to be oriented to a windows system.

Answer (score 0):

To find it from Windows OS,

1. Open command prompt and change the directory to tomcat/tomee **/bin** directory.
2. Type `catalina.bat version`
3. It should print jre version details along with other informative details.

   Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\User\software\enterprise-server-tome...

   Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\User\software\enterprise-server-tome...

   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\User\software\enterprise-server-tome...

   Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"

   Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\User\software\enterprise-server-tome...

   Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11

   Server built:   Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC

   Server number:  8.5.11.0

   OS Name:        Windows 7

   OS Version:     6.1

   Architecture:   amd64

   JVM Version:    1.8.0_25-b18

   JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation