# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CollegeWebsite]]

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, unsupported-class-version

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CollegeWebsite]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1603)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:469)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:332)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:597)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/Servlets/AddCourse : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.Servlets.AddCourse)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2893)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1170)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClass(WebAnnotationSet.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

How can I overcome this error? My project was deployed on Eclipse easily but it can't deploy when I deploy it directly through Tomcat server.

Comment: Check one of these
TOMCAT_USER (tomcat config), CLASSPATH (tomcat config) or user permission for tomcat dirs

Answer (score 30):

You have a version conflict, please verify whether compiled version and JVM of Tomcat version are same.
you can do it by examining tomcat startup .bat , looking for JAVA_HOME

Comment: how can i check jre version of tomcat and eclipse m new to it....Thanx

Comment: how can i check jre and JDK version of tomcat and eclipse used m new to it....Thanx please help me!!

Comment: first check your tomcat's java_home and then in eclipse modify the compiler compatibility settings to match above java_home version

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the case because I had one application which was running earlier with the same configuration but not it doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

This error happens because of your Jre version of Eclipse and Tomcat are mismatched ..either change eclipse one to tomcat one or ViceVersa..

Both should be same ..`Java version` mismatched ..Check it

Comment: how can i check jre version of tomcat and eclipse m new to it....Thanx

Comment: to check apache java version   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957851/how-do-i-find-what-java-version-tomcat6-is-using

Comment: to see in eclipse   Window > Prefrences > Java > Installed JREs

Comment: I just configured the build path: project -> right click -> build paht -> library -> check whether the jre version is correct; if not, remove it and add the right one.

Comment: @Suresh Atta: I have done almost everything. But in vain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753473/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-failed-to-start-component-standardserve

Comment: @PhilipRego Please do not read only answers, help youself by read comments. Comments are part of the answer.