# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException when trying to start Glassfish server with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, glassfish

I have been busy building a REST application with angularjs frontend, using a MAVEN jersey-quickstart-webapp, developed on Eclipse using the GLASSFISH webserver. Today when I started to do some development on the project, when I tried to start the server in eclipse and deploy the webapp, I got the following error message displayed in the eclipse error window:

```
cannot Deploy pododdle
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pododdle.dao.CategoryListService.
Please see server.log for more details.
```

It should be noted that I have not knowingly changed the JRE/JDK of Eclipse or Glassfish.
The server.log shows this error (it is repeated 3/4 times for each launch):

```
ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pododdle.dao.CategoryListService
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5985)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pododdle.dao.CategoryListService
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5977)
... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pododdle.dao.CategoryListService
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:308)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkResourceClassFields(IntrospectionModeller.java:223)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:139)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:792)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:463)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:182)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:348)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5732)
... 65 more
```

I have seen a similar question about this error on Tomcat here: [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CollegeWebsite]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750747/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-failed-to-start-component-standardengin)

As per this question, it says this can be caused by Eclipse and Tomcat using different JRE's. I have the following JRE running in Eclipse:

```
jdk1.8.0_73
```

The question is about Tomcat, so I tried to set JAVA_HOME on my Glassfish server by adding the following line to the ansev.bat for my glassfish server:

```
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

This was suggested by this answer: [How do I specify the jdk for a glassfish domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444959/how-do-i-specify-the-jdk-for-a-glassfish-domain)

However I am not sure if this is what I am looking for

This has not fixed the problem - it still gives the same error. Does anybody know what might be going wrong? Why would it suddenly stop working, and have I set the JRE for GLASSFISH correctly? How do I check what version of the JRE the GLASSFISH installation is using?

All help much appreciated....

**EDIT 1:**
As per Mike in the comments section reckons I am barking up the wrong tree - because it is a ClassNotFoundException that is being thrown, it looks like it is building incorrectly. Here is the server startup logging that appears in the console prior to the error:

```
2016-10-17T09:13:50.769+0100|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
2016-10-17T09:13:50.770+0100|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2016-10-17T09:13:50.861+0100|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2016-10-17T09:13:50.863+0100|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2016-10-17T09:13:50.865+0100|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2016-10-17T09:13:50.964+0100|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2016-10-17T09:13:51.008+0100|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2016-10-17T09:13:51.155+0100|Warning: Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
2016-10-17T09:13:51.230+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 54ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2016-10-17T09:13:51.242+0100|Warning: Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
2016-10-17T09:13:51.245+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2016-10-17T09:13:51.247+0100|Warning: Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
2016-10-17T09:13:51.251+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2016-10-17T09:13:51.279+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2016-10-17T09:13:51.280+0100|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (1,326ms), startup services(616ms), total(1,942ms)
2016-10-17T09:13:51.343+0100|Info: JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
2016-10-17T09:13:51.403+0100|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2016-10-17T09:13:51.404+0100|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@27d57a2c as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@597f48df.
2016-10-17T09:13:51.418+0100|Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://PododdlePC:8686/jndi/rmi://PododdlePC:8686/jmxrmi
2016-10-17T09:13:53.709+0100|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
2016-10-17T09:13:55.620+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:57.095+0100|Info: Java security manager is disabled.
2016-10-17T09:13:57.096+0100|Info: Entering Security Startup Service.
2016-10-17T09:13:57.101+0100|Info: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2016-10-17T09:13:57.187+0100|Info: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2016-10-17T09:13:57.632+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2016-10-17T09:13:57.637+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2016-10-17T09:13:57.638+0100|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2016-10-17T09:13:57.665+0100|Info: Created virtual server server
2016-10-17T09:13:57.667+0100|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2016-10-17T09:13:57.937+0100|Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2016-10-17T09:13:57.938+0100|Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2016-10-17T09:13:59.082+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.180+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.181+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.182+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.182+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.183+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.184+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.184+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.185+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.185+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.186+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.217+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.218+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.218+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.219+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.219+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.220+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.221+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.221+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.222+0100|Info: visiting unvisited references
2016-10-17T09:13:59.584+0100|Info: WELD-000900: 2.2.13 (Final)
2016-10-17T09:14:00.712+0100|WARN: WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PostActivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2016-10-17T09:14:00.712+0100|WARN: WELD-001700: Interceptor annotation class javax.ejb.PrePassivate not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2016-10-17T09:14:00.986+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:00.994+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:00.999+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.004+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.007+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.008+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.009+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.011+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.015+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.017+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.017+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.044+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.044+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.046+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.048+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.050+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.052+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.054+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.054+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.055+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.057+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.058+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.059+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:01.060+0100|WARN: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
2016-10-17T09:14:03.606+0100|Severe: WebModule[/pododdle]StandardWrapper.Throwable
```

Do this log point to anything obvious?

Comment: You're going down the wrong path here. The key bit of information is this line: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pododdle.dao.CategoryListService`. Have you checked that it's building correctly and packaging all your dependencies properly?

Comment: Hi Mike, not sure how to check they are loading properly. What do you recommend? I've updated the question with the full server start log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Mike in the comments suggested, it was likely there was something wrong with how the project was being built, due to this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pododdle.dao.CategoryListService
```

I looked into this, and he was right! Two jar files that I had on my builpath were mysteriously missing! They were:

```
jersey-media-multipart-2.21.1.jar
mimepull-1.9.3.jar
```

I have no idea how the jar files were deleted from the /lib directory of the glassfish server, maybe I shouldn't have drunk that extra bottle of whiskey. Once they were added back in, everything suddenly worked hunky dory. A little baffled by the error - i would have thought it would give a compile error if the jar wasn't available. Anyhow, 5 days lost due to another annoying error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that after cleaning the project that the dist (build folder) is empty. if not, delete its content manually. Also check that the libraries folder has all the needed libraries for all project layers and the class path of the IDE is set in the right way. Check the libraries folder too for duplicated jars. if you find some delete them manually then restart the server and clean and build the project again. It worked this way.