# Jersey-multipart in glassfish 4.1.1 error @FormDataParam

Tags: file, file-upload, jersey-2.0, glassfish-4

I I have imported jersey-multipart and I have used @FormaDataParam.

There is an error that project isn't deployed because of the annotation. Look at [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMDho.png).
I hope someone give me solution.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What the server log says?

Comment: Severe:   Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: .....................................................
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: This issue is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072181/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-when-trying-to-start-glassfish-server-wit