# Tomcat - Failed to start component when versions don't conflict

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to work with servlets, so I created a Java EE project on a Tomcat server. As you can see below, I have an environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, which holds the path to JDK 10. The Java version also defaults to 10, however when I start my Tomcat server, I get the highlighted error.

[image]

The problem arose after I created a servlet and tried to map it like in the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

In my project I also use the 10th version of Java. I don't quite get what the problem is here, so any hint would help.

**P.S.:** similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750747/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-failed-to-start-component-standardengin) did not solve my problem

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using? It looks like you are using IntelliJ. Did you follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes, I am using Intellij. The Tomcat version is 8.5.57

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash please take a look at the edits I've made to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL pattern must start with a `/`.

Replace

```
<url-pattern>add</url-pattern>
```

with

```
<url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
```