# IN WINDOWS, How do I find what Java version Tomcat is using?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, version

The title tells it all. I searched the web and here, and nothing was easy or clear or obvious, except for perhaps making a JSP page with the follwing in it:

```
System.out.println("JVM Version: " +System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
System.out.println("JVM Vendor: " +System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor"));
```

I did see [this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957851/how-do-i-find-what-java-version-tomcat6-is-using) about Linux, but I knew that already.

Comment: Enable your echo ON in your startup.sh and catalina.sh to know all the parameter information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the next in a JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Tomcat Version</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Tomcat Version</h2>
        <pre><%=pageContext.getServletContext().getServerInfo()%></pre>
        <h2>Servlet Version</h2>
        <pre><%=pageContext.getServletContext().getMajorVersion()%>.<%=pageContext.getServletContext().getMinorVersion()%></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry, scriptlets are no longer recommended. Better with JSTL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Tomcat Version</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Tomcat Version</h2>
        <pre>${pageContext.servletContext.serverInfo}</pre>
        <h2>Servlet Version</h2>
        <pre>${pageContext.servletContext.majorVersion}.${pageContext.servletContext.minorVersion}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plus one for the JSTL and JSP(?) versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the catalina.bat file to know about the Java version, which is located in bin directory. You can also set your preferred JDK in this file by setting "`JAVA_HOME`" pointing to your Java Development Kit Installation. You can make the `@echo ON` to get more information about the environment. This is generally used for debugging and checking the ENV parameters.BY default, tomcat will choose the default Java version. `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `java -version` to find out more details

Comment: tomcat tries other java versions first, then settles for the default java. 'echo'ing $JAVA_HOME doesn't reflect the java version in the link '/usr/lib/jvm/java-default', Just what is in /etc/environment modified by /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile  followed by ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile. When JAVA is used during the start up of any service, only the /etc/environment seems to have any effect. YMMV, but that's whay I find on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

You can get your server information from `ServletContext`. See this sample;

```
<%= application.getServerInfo() %>
```

Then please check this [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) documentation.