# Tomcat JVM version different from JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, tomcat

I wanted to make my Tomcat `JVM` version be 7. So I followed in the instruction here: [How to change Java version used by TOMCAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072260/how-to-change-java-version-used-by-tomcat) and changed my `JAVA_HOME` to be my jdk7 directory.

To make sure, here is the command:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

I restarted Tomcat. I wanted to verify, and ran the command I got from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10822328/998318

```
$ /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh version
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 1: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote: not found
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 2: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099: not found
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 3: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false: not found
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 4: /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false: not found
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Server built:   Apr 8 2014 08:47:08
Server number:  7.0.28.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_79-b14
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

and indeed I see that JVM version is 1.7.0_79-b14

**BUT** when i go to the online manager I see this:
[image]

what's going on? and indeed I started this whole process because my war isn't getting deployed because of a version mismatch:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer : 
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer)
```

**update**
as requested, here is the output for running java -version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Maybe JRE_HOME is wrong?

Comment: @MyPasswordIsLasercats but JRE_HOME is the same as JAVA_HOME and it is correct

Comment: Check your PATH. It should include JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: also just check the version using java -version in command line

Comment: just check the target  JRE with `echo $JRE_HOME` command.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem is just from the information given. I'd suggest checking whether Tomcat's startup script has overriden either environment variable locally

Comment: @SaviNuclear $JRE_HOME is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `*nix`, create the setenv.sh file with the following content:

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre
CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/tomcat.pid"
```

Comment: this worked, kind of. I used `export JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"` without the second line and it was all fixed!

Answer (score 3):

According [this article](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/4-ways-to-change-jre-for-tomcat) there are 4 different ways:

**1. Changing JRE by updating JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME**

> This way is very simple to implement **but it works only for Tomcat installed from a zip distribution** (in contrast to Tomcat installed as a service).

- if only the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set, Tomcat will run under the JRE as part of the `JDK` specified by the `JAVA_HOME` variable. Therefore, we change `JRE` for Tomcat by updating this variable.
- If both the `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` environment variables are set, the JRE_HOME is preferred. Here’s an example of a valid value for the `JRE_HOME` variable (path on Windows):

```
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

**2. Changing JRE by using “setenv” script**

> We can change the JRE for Tomcat by setting the `JRE_HOME` variable in a script file called setenv.bat (on Windows) or setenv.sh (on `*nix`). This file does not exist by default, so create such file and place it under `CATALINA_BASE\bin` directory (`CATALINA_BASE` is the Tomcat installation directory).

On Windows, create the `setenv.bat` file with the following content:

```
set "JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre"
exit /b 0
```

**3. Changing JRE in Tomcat service manager**

For a Tomcat installation which is installed as a service (on Windows), we can change the version of JRE that runs Tomcat by configuring the Java Virtual Machine setting in the Tomcat service manager program (e.g. `Tomcat7w.exe`), as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

**4. Changing JRE in Eclipse IDE**

> To change JRE version for a Tomcat runtime in Eclipse, go to the menu Window > Preferences. In the Preferences dialog, open the Server > Runtime Environments node, select a Tomcat version in the list, and then click the Edit button

Check further info in [linked](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/4-ways-to-change-jre-for-tomcat) article